# how to update provider data screen into homescreen

Tags: flutter, listview, layout, render, provider

[image][image]

1. first pic :  another screen with provider
2. first pic source
3. ```
   class  MainSliderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
     // const MainSliderScreen extends({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       final currentPosition =
           Provider.of<Position?>(context); // Position에 ?를 하니까, 로딩할 때 에러가 발생안함!!
       final placesProvider =
           Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>?>(context, listen: false);
       final geoService = GeoLocatorService();
       final markerService = MarkerService();

       return FutureProvider(
         create: (context) => placesProvider,
         initialData: null,
         child: Scaffold(
           body: (currentPosition != null)
               ? Consumer<List<Place>?>(
                   /* child: ElevatedButton(
                       child: Text('메인화면으로'),
                       onPressed: () {
                         Navigator.pop(context);
                       }),*/
                   builder: (_, places, __) {
                     /* var markers;
                     if ((places != null)) {
                       markers = markerService.getMarkers(places);
                     } else {
                       markers = <Marker>[];
                     }*/
                     // if ((places != null)) {
                     return Column(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         Padding(
                           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
                           child: ElevatedButton(
                               child: Text('지도화면으로'),
                               onPressed: () {
                                 Navigator.pop(context);
                               }),
                         ),
                         /* SizedBox(
                           height: 2.0,
                         ),*/
                         Expanded(
                           child: ListView.builder(
                               // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                               itemCount: places!.length,
                               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                 return FutureProvider(
                                   create: (context) => geoService.getDistance(
                                       currentPosition.latitude,
                                       currentPosition.longitude,
                                       places[index].geometry.location.lat,
                                       places[index].geometry.location.lng),
                                   initialData: null,
                                   child: Card(
                                     child: ListTile(
                                       title: Text(
                                         places[index].name,
                                       ),
                                       subtitle: Column(
                                         crossAxisAlignment:
                                             CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                         children: <Widget>[
                                           (places[index].rating != null)
                                               ? Row(
                                                   children: <Widget>[
                                                     RatingBarIndicator(
                                                       rating:
                                                           places[index].rating,
                                                       itemBuilder: (context,
                                                               index) =>
                                                           Icon(Icons.star,
                                                               color:
                                                                   Colors.amber),
                                                       itemCount: 5,
                                                       itemSize: 10.0,
                                                       direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                                     )
                                                   ],
                                                 )
                                               : Row(),
                                           SizedBox(
                                             height: 5.0,
                                           ),
                                           Consumer<double?>(builder:
                                               (context, kilometers, widget) {
                                             return (kilometers != null)
                                                 ? Text(
                                                     // 일단  miles로 나타내고 , 추후에 킬로미터로 바꿈.
                                                     // '${places[index].vicinity}\u00b7 ${(meters / 1609).round()} mi')
                                                     '${places[index].vicinity}\u00b7 ${(kilometers / 1000).round()} km')
                                                 : Container();
                                           })
                                         ],
                                       ),
                                       trailing: IconButton(
                                         icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
                                         color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                         // onPressed 누르면  예약하기로 넘어가기
                                         // markerService에  InfoWindow에 화면 크게 해서
                                         // 웬만한 정보 다 담기
                                         onPressed: () {
                                           /* _launchMapsUrl(
                                           places[index]
                                               .geometry
                                               .location
                                               .lat,
                                           places[index]
                                               .geometry
                                               .location
                                               .lng);*/
                                         },
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 );
                               }),
                         ),
                       ],
                     );
                     /* } else {
                       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                     }*/
                   },
                 )
               : Center(
                   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                 ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```
4. second pic : home screen
   4-1. secodn pic source :
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 30, right: 30),
   body: SafeArea(
   child: ListView(
   children: [
   //shrinkWrap: true,
   HomeHeader(),
   SizedBox(height: 20),
   MainSliderScreen(),
   SizedBox(height: 20),
   ],
   ),
   )
   );
   }

i  tried to another screen with provider into homescreen .

at that time , error like this

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#38422 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAY